# Shadow not working properly in eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

[image]

There is a spot light above. The shadow is very unnatural there is no shadow where the leg touches the ground us there any fix?  I have turned up samples to 100, high bitrate, 2k cascade and cube, contact shadow on. But the problems exists.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (a very simplified version of it)? https://blend-exchange.com/